# notifyDataSetChanged() from DialogFragment to GridView adapter in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, callback, android-arrayadapter

I have a Main activity, that holds NavigationDrawerFragment (taken from android studio template)
GridViewAdapter has OnLongClickListener, that runs SettingsFragment through the callback in Main:

in Main:

```
  public void ShowSettings(Drink drink, int position) {
        // DialogFragment.show() will take care of adding the fragment
        // in a transaction.  We also want to remove any currently showing
        // dialog, so make our own transaction and take care of that here.
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
        if (prev != null) {
            ft.remove(prev);
        }
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        // Create and show the dialog.
        DialogFragment settings = FragmentSettings.newInstance(drink, position);

        settings.show(ft, "FragmentSettings");
```

GridViewAdapter:

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener {

    private ArrayList<Drink> listDrink = new ArrayList<Drink>();
    private Activity activity;
    private Context mContext;
    private GridViewAdapterCallback callback;

    public GridViewAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Drink> listDrink) {
        super();
        this.listDrink = listDrink;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public GridViewAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listDrink.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Drink getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listDrink.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }




    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder view;
        LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);

            view.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);

            view.imgViewFlag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            view.txtViewCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCount);

            convertView.setTag(view);
        } else {
            view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        view.txtViewTitle.setText(listDrink.get(position).getProductName());
        switch (listDrink.get(position).getType()) {
            case (1):
                view.imgViewFlag.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_beer);
                break;
            case (2):
                view.imgViewFlag.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_dark);
                break;
            default:
                view.imgViewFlag.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shot);
                break;


        }

        int count = callback.SqliteCountProducts(listDrink.get(position).getProductName());
        view.txtViewCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
//        notifyDataSetChanged();

        return convertView;
    }

    public void setCallback(GridViewAdapterCallback callback) {

        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
//        Log.d("My_Log", "On_click:" + position);
        callback.SqliteSave(listDrink.get(position));
        notifyDataSetInvalidated();


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
//        Log.d("My_Log", "On_long_click:" + position);
        callback.ShowSettings(listDrink.get(position), position);
        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        return true;
    }

    public void UpdateGrid() {
        notifyDataSetInvalidated();

    }


    public interface GridViewAdapterCallback {

        public int SqliteCountProducts(String product);

        public void SqliteSave(Drink drink);

        public void ShowSettings(Drink drink, int position);
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imgViewFlag;
        public TextView txtViewTitle;
        public TextView txtViewCount;
    }


}
```

GridFragment, that holds GridViewAdapter

```
public class GridFragment extends Fragment {
    //    ArrayList<Drink> listDrink = new ArrayList<Drink>();
    public GridViewAdapter mAdapter;

    public GridFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static GridFragment newInstance() {
        GridFragment fragment = new GridFragment();
        return fragment;
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_grid, container, false);
        // prepared arraylist and passed it to the Adapter class
        mAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(getActivity(), ((Main) getActivity()).PrepareDefaultArray());
        GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gvMain);

        mAdapter.setCallback((GridViewAdapter.GridViewAdapterCallback) view.getContext());
        gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(mAdapter);
        gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(mAdapter);



        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        UpdateArray();


    }
    public void UpdateArray() {
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

onResume works, but only after GridView item is slided behind the screen and back

I don't know how to make it work correct. :/

Content provider?

I can not make another callback to main - because it causes loop

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you put `UpdateArray()` in onCreate()? mAdapter is not yet instanced.

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    UpdateArray();


}
```

So move `UpdateArray()` from `onCreate()` to `onCreateView()`, after `gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);`

**UPDATE:**

And also comment `notifyDataSetInvalidated ()`, because:

> > public void  notifyDataSetInvalidated (): 
> >      Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data is no longer valid or available. Once invoked this adapter is no longer valid and should not report further data set changes.

Comment: a trace of experiments)
thank you for response, but didn't help :(
maybe i need to 
GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
to ArrayAdapter? because ArrayAdapter, as i've read, sends notifydatasetchanges() automatically?

Comment: ArrayAdapter implements BaseAdapter, so will be no diffrence and notifyDataSetChanged works for both

Comment: Mmmm, yeah, I've already tried ArrayAdapter) Is there any method to find instance of my adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: comment/remove `notifyDataSetInvalidated ()` then `notifyDataSetChanged()` should work, have you tried?

Comment: It works, but grid view updates not momentally, but after moving grid up and down

Comment: I suppose your question is solved, for other issues maybe you have to improve your adapter, especially in `getView()`